# Carousel in Lightning component - External framework (Slick)

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, framework

I am trying to import the [Slick](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) framework in a lightning component to get a complete carousel.
I am doing this with **ltng:require**

```
  <ltng:require styles="{!join(',',
                  $Resource.slick + 'slick-1.8.1/slick/slick-theme.css' ,
                  $Resource.slick +'slick-1.8.1/slick/slick.css')}" 
                scripts="{!join(',',
                  $Resource.slick + 'slick-1.8.1/slick/slick.js',
                  $Resource.jQuery)}"
                afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.afterLoad}" />
```

this line of the imports does not work

```
$Resource.slick +'slick-1.8.1/slick/slick.css'
```

I get this Error when i try:
[image]

What could be the Problem?

Answer (score 0):

The path names should start with `/`. I'm not sure about Slick specifically, but it may also simply not be compatible with Lightning Locker Service.

```
  <ltng:require styles="{!join(',',
                  $Resource.slick + '/slick-1.8.1/slick/slick-theme.css' ,
                  $Resource.slick +'/slick-1.8.1/slick/slick.css')}" 
                scripts="{!join(',',
                  $Resource.slick + '/slick-1.8.1/slick/slick.js',
                  $Resource.jQuery)}"
                afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.afterLoad}" />
```

Comment: yes you right , I add '/' before paths and I also delete all comments from all CSS and JS files . it's not make error but just not working .